# Magento CSS on tabs

Tags: javascript, css, magento, tabs, block

I'm doing redesign on default magento theme, so I want TABS on product page,and I find tutorial:

http://www.atwix.com/magento/adding-tabs-on-the-product-page/

-I'm doing step by step like in tutorial
Everything is ok with functionaly, but it wont add css to tabs, so i have just links, i was checked:

1.Name of class in catalog.xml and styles.css it's ok.
2.Tryng to see with firebug and chrome editor, there is no conected class in css :/

Anybody have any idea?

(Sorry for bad En)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this extension instead http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/magento-easytabs.html. It's a free one. you can also do some modification. if you want. Let me know if any problem